# xib file button with helper Class is not working

Tags: ios, swift

I have a xib file with a button inside it and two labels over the button which is hidden within an if statement, what I am trying to do is inside my helper method call a function named pledgeInterestView which is an alertView, I have added a target to the button and then a gesture recognizer to the parent view(this view encapsulates the labels and button), however the button is not functioning properly and the function is not being called? 
My xib file is fine and it loads perfectly, if that code is needed i can provide it

This is my helper method:

```
static func inflateProfileImageFunder(view:UIView){
    let content = ProfileImage()
    view.addSubview(content)
    content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let leadingDeviceData = NSLayoutConstraint(item: content, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let trailingDeviceData = NSLayoutConstraint(item: content, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let heightDeviceData = NSLayoutConstraint(item: content, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let topDeviceData = NSLayoutConstraint(item: content, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leadingDeviceData, trailingDeviceData, heightDeviceData, topDeviceData])

    let isFunder = LoginVC.isFunder
        if (!isFunder){
            print("Not a Funder")
            content.buttonViews.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            content.buttonViews.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
            content.buttonViews.isHidden = true
        }else{
            content.label2.isHidden = true
            content.label1.isHidden = true
            content.buttonTap.isEnabled = true
            content.buttonTap.setTitle("Pledge Interest", for: UIControlState.normal)
            content.buttonTap.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1), for: UIControlState.normal)
            let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.pledgeInterestView(_:)))
            content.buttonViews.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
            content.buttonViews.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}
func pledgeInterestView(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let content = PledgeInterest()

    content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    content.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 175).isActive = true
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "I can Provide", attributes: [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : #colorLiteral(red: 0.1657446325, green: 0.3779471517, blue: 0.6579626203, alpha: 1)
        ])
    let alert = AlertController(title: "", message: "")
    alert.setValue(attributedString, forKey: "attributedTitle")


    let okAction = AlertAction(title: "Pledge", style: .normal, handler: nil)
    let cancelAction = AlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .normal, handler: nil)

    alert.add(cancelAction)
    alert.add(okAction)
    alert.contentView.addSubview(content)

    content.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alert.contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    content.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alert.contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    content.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alert.contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    content.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:alert.contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    content.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alert.contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true


    alert.view.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1657446325, green: 0.3779471517, blue: 0.6579626203, alpha: 1)
    alert.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

[The code for my Xib file, the buttonView has 3 elements inside it, 2 labels and 1 button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezsfI.png)

[the view I am trying to add a tap to(ProfileImage)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ek66.png)

Comment: It looks like you have --- `content` which is a `ProfileImage()` (which is a `UIView`?) which contains `label1` and `label2` and `buttonTap` (which is a `UIButton`?) and `buttonViews` (which is a `UIView`?), and you're adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` (with a target action) to `buttonViews` ... but you're not adding a target action to `buttonTap`? This is very confusing... maybe show an image identifying all these elements?

Comment: @DonMag the images have been uploaded, i did add the target to the button but it still does not call the function in the #selector(), i have set breakpoints to check and it hits the add target but when i press it, it does not retrigger or go into the function, also in the VC that im calling the helper method its under view did load

Comment: Are you trying to get taps on the "Pledge Interest" button? Or are you trying to track a tap anywhere on the entire view - the picture, the white box, the blue button, the whole bounding-box background? If it is only on the button, then there is absolutely no need for a `UITapGestureRecognizer` - you can (and should) simply use the normal `.touchUpInside` action of the button.

Comment: yes on the button, however i have tried the normal touch up inside and it still refuses to work so i added a tap to the entire view and it still refuses to engage

Comment: OK - two suggestions... 1. When your app is running and your ProfileImage view is visible, use `Debug View Hierarchy` to make sure there are no transparent views covering the button. 2. Connect the Button to a `@IBAction` *inside* your ProfileImage class. Have it just `print("got it")` to the debug console. If *that* works, then you really should have no trouble with `content.buttonTap.addTarget(self, action: #selector()...`

Comment: @DonMag i just did the debug view hierachy and there is the stackView on the button!! SNAP! Thank You DonMag, i can now fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved this issue i was having by simply adding an extra static func in my helper class like this:

```
 static func inflateProfileImageFunder(view:UIView) {
    let content = ProfileImage()
    view.addSubview(content)
    content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let leadingDeviceData = NSLayoutConstraint(item: content, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let trailingDeviceData = NSLayoutConstraint(item: content, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let heightDeviceData = NSLayoutConstraint(item: content, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let topDeviceData = NSLayoutConstraint(item: content, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leadingDeviceData, trailingDeviceData, heightDeviceData, topDeviceData])

    let isFunder = LoginVC.isFunder
        if (!isFunder){
            print("Not a Funder")
            content.buttonViews.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            content.buttonViews.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
            content.buttonViews.isHidden = true
        }else{
            content.label2.isHidden = true
            content.label1.isHidden = true
            content.buttonTap.isEnabled = true
            content.buttonTap.setTitle("Pledge Interest", for: UIControlState.normal)
            content.buttonTap.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1), for: UIControlState.normal)
            content.buttonTap.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pledgeInterestView), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    }
}

static func pledgeInterestView(){
    pledge()
}

static func pledge() {
    let content = PledgeInterest()

    content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    content.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 175).isActive = true
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "I can Provide", attributes: [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : #colorLiteral(red: 0.1657446325, green: 0.3779471517, blue: 0.6579626203, alpha: 1)
        ])
    let alert = AlertController(title: "", message: "")
    alert.setValue(attributedString, forKey: "attributedTitle")

    let okAction = AlertAction(title: "Pledge", style: .normal, handler: nil)
    let cancelAction = AlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .normal, handler: nil)

    alert.add(cancelAction)
    alert.add(okAction)
    alert.contentView.addSubview(content)

    content.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alert.contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    content.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alert.contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    content.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alert.contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    content.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:alert.contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    content.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alert.contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    alert.view.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1657446325, green: 0.3779471517, blue: 0.6579626203, alpha: 1)

    alert.present()

}
```

This worked perfectly for me